# Computation with Futures avoiding Await method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, future, futuretask

I have funtion which is calling  computeParallel() function which is calling 3 Futures F1,F2,F3 and returning String as return type.

```
def computeParallel():String =
{

      val f1 = Future {  "ss" }
      val f2 = Future { "sss" }
      val f3 = Future { "ssss" }

      val result: Future[String] = for {
        r1 <- f1
        r2 <- f2
        r3 <- f3
      } yield (r1 + r2 + r3)

    Await.result(result,scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)



}
```

Using Await to collect the Aggregated Results.But People are saying usage of Await is Bad way of coding.

So i have used below one.Which is returning the Unit type.

```
        result.onComplete {
          case Success(res) => return res
        }
```

So if return Unit i cannot print anything.

can any help us.Is there anyother way to solve the problem

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Will promises help in this case .?

Comment: What do you need to do? print something? do something with the result?

Comment: I have to pass the result to some other function after collecting from here

Comment: Look at cats-effect IO or Monix, or ZIO

Comment: Then just `map` or `flatMap` or `foreach` your future with that function. - Do you understand that a future means an asynchronous computation, the moment you wait, you destroy that. So usually all the code should be adapted to be asynchronous. But this happens because you need it, if not why are you using futures in the first place?

Comment: Yeah like @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez said, you don't need to compute that, just map and pass that result to another function. result.map(otherFunction(_)) or just result.map(otherFunction)

Answer (score 2):

If `computeParallel` must return `String` you have to `Await.result`.

"Good way of coding" is to work with futures as soon as you get into them.

```
def computeParallel(): Future[String] = {
  val f1 = Future {  "ss" }
  val f2 = Future { "sss" }
  val f3 = Future { "ssss" }

  for {
    r1 <- f1
    r2 <- f2
    r3 <- f3
  } yield (r1 + r2 + r3)
} 

computeParallel().map(result => ???)
```

`return` normally shouldn't be used in Scala.

`onComplete` won't help because it

> runs on some arbitrary (unspecified) thread ...

and we don't block until it completes.

[Difference between Await.result and futures.onComplete in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043060/difference-between-await-result-and-futures-oncomplete-in-scala)

Promise can be completed to future so again you'll have `Future[String]` rather than `String`.

Comment: Thanks, If i used .map() or Oncomplete im not getting any result. if i try to print something with these functions it is like "List()" printed and exited from the runtime

Comment: If i had to mention the Thread.sleep() . Im not sure how much time it will execute exactly.

Comment: @Learnis Regarding `map` I can't answer, you didn't write your code with `map`. Regarding `Oncomplete` I already said that callback runs on a different thread and `computeParallel` finishes before.

Comment: @Learnis `Thread.sleep()` is blocking as well as `Await.result` is blocking